# How is /proc/[pid]/ns/mnt created by clone in kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel

I know `clone` function creates `/proc/[pid]/ns/mnt` link. But I couldn’t find where it calls something like `proc_mkdir` to create such directory.

Comment: It doesn't create directories in /proc. /proc works by searching for kernel data structures when you perform path lookup on it.

Comment: @root I looked into the readlink api, but didn’t figure out how does it work. Could you please point out some information for /proc/[pid] directory lookup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`clone()` doesn't create anything in `/proc`.

When you open `/proc/[pid]/ns/mnt`, the path lookup logic in VFS finds `/proc` and then gets to [`proc_root_lookup()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.18.1/source/fs/proc/root.c#L320).

From there it goes to `proc_pid_lookup()` to `proc_pid_instantiate()`, which creates, on the fly, an in-memory directory inode for `/proc/[pid]` via `proc_pid_make_inode()`.